# Update multiple rows replacing a character in certain position in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, design-patterns, field

Imagine that you have a column with a bunch of fields like this:

```
ab
abc
abcd
...
```

I would like to transform these fields using a single query to something like this:

```
a_b
ab_c
abc_d
...
```

That is, inserting an underscore just before the last letter.

I could do it in a one by one basis:

```
update test set name = 'a_b' where name ='ab';
update test set name = 'ab_c' where name ='abc';
update test set name = 'abc_d' where name ='abcd';
```

But being a high number of fields to update, I figure there must be a better way to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this query -

```
UPDATE test SET name = INSERT(name, LENGTH(name), 0, '_');
```

Answer (score 1):

Use some of the string manipulation functions, something like:

```
SET fieldname = CONCAT(LEFT(fieldname, LENGTH(fieldname)-1),"_",RIGHT(fieldname,1))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the SUBSTRING AND [LENGTH](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_length) functions:

```
UPDATE test
   SET name = SUBSTRING(name, 0, LENGTH(name) - 1) + '_' + SUBSTRING(name, -1)
```